# How to interpret a UML 2.5 State Machine diagram?

Tags: uml, state, statechart

I am in need of identifying all the basic elements of a UML 2.5 State Machine Diagram. Unfortunately , there seems to be a lot of ambiguity on the notation of those diagrams, as there are a lot of different variations online.

My interpretation is that every state machine diagram , consists of a number of states and a number of transitions.

Every state has:

- an optional **entry** action
- an optional **do** action
- an optional **exit** action

Every transition has:

- a triggering **event**,
- an optional **precondition**
- a **transition action** (post-condition).

My understanding of how the notation works can be summarized in Figure 1 (example of an electric door functionality following the notation ***[precondition] Event / [Transition Action]***) and in Figure 2.

**Example:** When an ***event*** is triggered (e.g close button pressed), the ***precondition*** (if any)  is evaluated (e.g is the doorway empty) and if the ***precondition*** is satisfied,  a ***transition action*** (e.g close door) is triggered.

**Figure 1**
[image: Electric Door State Machine]

**Figure 2**
[image]

My questions:

1. Is the ***Transition Action*** the realization of the transition or is
   simply an action that happens during the transition. In plain words,
   if ***the transition action/s*** go wrong, will the transition (new
   state) be successful? My question basically derives from the fact
   that a lot of sources suggest that instead of using a ***transition
   action***, you can use an ***entry action*** when you arrive at the new
   state. In my understanding though a ***transition action*** is the
   realization of the transition and hence happens before entering the
   new state, in comparison to the ***entry action*** that happens
   immediately after arriving at the new state. So these are two completely different types of action in respect to the transition itself and time. It's crucial for me here to understand the ***timing*** of those actions.
2. Is my general interpretation correct? (e.g. my understanding of what an event, post-condition and transition-action may be from Figure 1)

I know that there a dozen of variations of state machine diagrams, hence the different representations / interpretations but i am interested on the UML 2.5 one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Transition Action is what UML 2.5 states as association end of a transition:

> **effect** : Behavior [0..1]{subsets Element::ownedElement} (opposite A_effect_transition::transition) Specifies an optional behavior to be performed when the Transition fires.

While the `<<entry>>` of a state is a behavior assigned to the state itself. That is, it will be triggered from where ever the transition comes from. In contrast the above **effect** is only trigger along the transition.

The effect can not "go wrong". What ever behavior is performed, is performed. No condition is checked here.

Whether a transition is triggered can be controlled by the `[guard]` which you wrongly named `[precondition]`. (One can start arguing, but you need to go with `[guard]`.)

> **guard** : Constraint [0..1]{subsets Namespace::ownedRule} (opposite A_guard_transition::transition)
>   A guard is a Constraint that provides a fine-grained control over the firing of the Transition. The guard is evaluated when an Event occurrence is dispatched by the StateMachine. If the guard is true at that time, the Transition may be enabled, otherwise, it is disabled. Guards should be pure expressions without side effects. Guard expressions with side effects are ill formed.

With respect to timing you can think of a token traveling along the states. When the guard lets you pass, the `<<exit>>` behavior is performed. Then the transition's `effect` and finally the `<<entry>>` behavior of the next state.

Comment: Thomas thank you for your answer. In respect to the transition action/effect, you are suggesting that this is not the "realization of the transition" ? It can be any action/behavior? I am looking at it from a risk analysis point of view, so i am trying to understand exactly each element in the diagram and how something can go wrong. By the way, what is a good source to understand the diagrams? I used http://www.uml-diagrams.org/  (where guard is actually called pre-condition..)

Comment: Well, the realization of the transition is the full set (guard, effect, trigger). You can put any behavior in the effect and it will perform along with the token traveling through the transition. I can't recommend much. The uml-diagrams are for sure a good source. The UML spec itself is not a learning source. It's written for tool developers (and maybe nerds). Of course you can learn a lot here with questions the way you asked :-)